# Create a dropdown list using multiple models in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm trying to populate a drop down list from a table called supplier_table but I'm currently trying to do this within the view/create of a system_user table. I'm not quite sure how to use different models within a page.

This is my code from the create page:

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model,
//(>w<) for dropdown 
'companyval'=>$companyval)); ?>
```

Problem is that $companyval is from a different model and currently, the model that is being used for this page is the one for this particular "create".

I'm not sure I explained it clearly, but if you have any questions, just comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understood from the question is that you want to show a dropdown from some  other model in view of a different controller. In Yii you can do it like this.

I suppose you are using `CActiveForm` and have supplier Model with supplier_id in user table. You can modify if this solves the issue. add this code in view / _form of controller

```
    <?php $supplier = Supplier::model()->findAll();
          $list = CHtml::listData($supplier ,'id','name'); 
          echo $form->DropDownList($model,'supplier_id', 
          $list, array('prompt'=>'Select Supplier')); ?>
```

Comment: I have a question, in the line "Supplier::model()" Does the Supplier mean the actual name of the table inside the database?

Comment: Supplier is model class name

Comment: it is Model name. Supplier is model name